postgres: Dynamic multiple updates syntax error
Getting PostgresError: syntax error on this query:
exports.updateMatches = async ({ payload: { matches } }) => {
  const formattedMatches = objArrToArr(matches);
  const cols = Object.keys(matches[0]);
  const colsWOId = cols
    .filter((item) => item !== "id")
    .map((item) => camelToSnake(item));
    
  return await sql`
        update matches
        set ${colsWOId.map((col) => `${sql(col)} = excluded.${sql(col)}`).join(", ")}
        from (values ${sql(formattedMatches)}) as excluded(${cols.join(", ")})
        where matches.id = (excluded.id):: int
            returning *;`;
};

note: using postgres npm package, they dont support sql.identifier()/sql.raw(). tried to follow the sql format from their official documentation:
Multiple updates in one query:
const users = [
  [1, 'John', 34],
  [2, 'Jane', 27],
]
await sql`
  update users set name = update_data.name, age = (update_data.age)::int
  from (values ${sql(users)}) as update_data (id, name, age)
  where users.id = (update_data.id)::int
  returning users.id, users.name, users.age
`     

Error details from the library:
PostgresError: syntax error at or near "FROM"
at ErrorResponse (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/connection.js:788:26)
at handle (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/connection.js:474:6)
at Socket.data (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/connection.js:315:9)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23)
at cachedError (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/query.js:170:23)
at new Query (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/query.js:36:24)
at sql (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/node_modules/postgres/cjs/src/index.js:112:11)
at exports.updateMatches (/home/raf/apps/tourna-pro/api/src/service/tournament-format.js:139:24)
severity_local: 'ERROR',
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42601',
position: '148',
file: 'scan.l',
line: '1242',
routine: 'scanner_yyerror'   


If you're getting a syntax error, you're getting an error message, and that message should appear in your question. Please [edit] to provide that complete, exact error message. It's on the screen right in front of you, so there's  no excuse for not providing it to us as well.

updated, not sure if the error details will be enough for you @KenWhite

Examining the generated query will likely expose the syntax error.

Please review[mre] and update the post with sufficient information to reproduce the problem. At least, add the text of the gerenated query. Why is a second query included in the post?

the library dont provide generated query, if it provided i could fix myself. the reason for 2nd query explained in the post. anyway appreciate your moderative suggestions, although unable to provide actual suggestion which helps solving the problem in real life.

Get the generating query by using .describe as documented in the Advanced Query Methods section of the Postgres.js documentation.

Can you try with this.
const updatedUsers = await sql`
  UPDATE users 
  SET name = update_data.name, 
      age = (update_data.age)::int
  FROM (VALUES ${sql(users.map(user => `(${user.join(',')})`))}) AS update_data (id, name, age)
  WHERE users.id = (update_data.id)::int
  RETURNING users.id, users.name, users.age;

Your error mostly seems to be from not properly handling the users input array

need to make SET col dynamic too
